# Hide ListView table header from the code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I want to hide a column of ListView based on the role from the code behind. Here's the mark-up and the code:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvTimeSheet" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="TimeSheet">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="thDelete" runat="server" Visible='<%# IsAdmin() %>'>
                         Select
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbMarkAsComplete" runat="server" onclick="selectMe(this)" Text=" &nbsp; Delete" />
            </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In the ListView layout template I have a `<th>` which has attribute `id="thDelete" runat="server" Visible='<%# IsAdmin() %>'` . In the code behind,

```
    Public Function IsAdmin() As Boolean

    If "user is admin" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

But that column id="thDelete" is visible all the time. How do I go about hiding the column based on some condition from the code behind? Thank you for any input.

Comment: Are you positive the IsAdmin function returns a false value?

Comment: Yes, even though I changed the function to return only False, it's still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags with the attribute runat="server" can't allow inclusion <% %>. Try this:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvTimeSheet" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="TimeSheet">
            <thead>
<% If IsAdmin() Then %>

                <tr>
                    <th id="thDelete" runat="server">
                         Select
                    </th>
                </tr>
<% End If %>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbMarkAsComplete" runat="server" onclick="selectMe(this)" Text=" &nbsp; Delete" />
            </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="TimeSheet">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="thDelete" runat="server" Visible='<%# If( IsAdmin().tostring()="True", "true", "false") %>'>
                     Select
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>`
```